# Pass data between views?

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

I'm using playframework 2.2 with twitter bootstrap. I have a general question to you about how I should model the following in play. Whether to use cache or session paramater and how I can bind child objects.

How it should be:

I have a form based view for an ORDER. I bind the data with Form[Order]. Any ORDER has a child object ADDRESS (the customer). In my form for the ORDER I have a button where it routes to the table view of all possible addresses, from here the user should be able to select an ADDRESS. After selecting the ADDRESS it should be submitted and the ORDER form should be displayed with a string representation of the ADDRESS.

1. The unsaved changes the user made to the ORDER before he selected the ADDRESS (customer) should not be lost.
2. Back on the ORDER form after selecting an ADDRESS, if the user now hits CANCEL no changes should be stored.
3. When saving the ORDER Form how can I save/bind the child objects (e.g. ADDRESS) too?

Can anybody tell me how I solve that use case best?

Many Thanks.